# Common protobuf data types in microservice architecture?

Tags: protocol-buffers, microservices, grpc

We are thinking of implementing some kind of microservice architecture. We will have software maintained by multiple teams and we would use grpc with protobuf 3 as a serialization mechanism for point to point communication. The goal is to decouple business logic from application logic on one hand and to allow UIs spanning multiple business contexts on the other hand.

Microservices will sometimes have to handle data similar or identical to data handled by other microservices.

In this context, is it advisable to extract those common proto3 data types, handle them separately and import them as dependencies into each microservice? That way they could be reused in multiple services.

Or is it better to focus on decoupling the microservices from each other by not sharing any (common) data types (share nothing architecture)?

Answer (score 3):

What should make you wonder is why multiple microservices will handle similar or identical data. This may mean that you are going too far in slicing your solution. Quoting [Sam Newman](http://samnewman.io/books/building_microservices/) - "*bounded contexts represent autonomous business domains (i.e., distinct business capabilities), and therefore are the appropriate starting point for identifying the dividing lines for microservices.*".

So I would say - there should be a good business reason to go deeper than the business domain -> microservice split.

One good comment about "sharing libraries/components" I've read recently is that soon this shared library/component becomes your bottleneck, any changes you make there will require a lot of regression testing across teams and the initial value of having it may be overshadowed by effort required to maintain it.

So as you can see, if you go microservices, I'd vote for share-nothing approach ;-)